# how to Create a new repository with github action workflow

Tags: github-actions

I'm looking for a solution to create a new github repository with github workflow actions.

it gets the name of the new repository with `workflow_dispatch` input.

```
on: 
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      repo_name:
        description: 'New Repository Name'
```

how complete this code to create a new repository with github workflow actions?

Comment: See https://github.com/repo-ctrl/create-repo-action

Comment: Hi @Yuseferi, please try and show your own effort and how that did not work when asking a question.

Comment: thanks, @eyllanesc . it gave me a basic idea of me how to fix it.